# Any thoughts on Improving a spring batch jobs restart speed?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which copies data from tables from one oracle schema to another.
To do this, I have written a partitioned job.
For example:

Case A:

I have a table A with 100000 rows and I split into 100 steps of 1000 rows each. all these inserts are done in parallel using ThreadPool task executor. If 4 steps failed due to some issue. I restarted the job, it successfully ran the failed 4 steps within seconds as I expected.

Case B:

Say a table A containing 32 million rows is to be copied from source to destination.
So I split this job into steps of 1000 rows each so 32000 steps are created.

Out of these 32000 steps 4 steps fails due to some db issue. When I try to restart this job, Spring batch just hangs or I dont know what processing is going on behind restart it just does not do anything. I waited for 5 hours and then killed the job.

so Can someone help me with what happens behind the restart, how the total number of steps affects the restart ? and what should I do to improve this speed?

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

**Updates:**

I was able to speed up the Case B by implementing PartitionNameProvider and was returning the names of failed steps alone via getPartitionNames during restart. Great. I was testing this restart with more number of failures and I have one more case now.

Case C:

If I have 20000 steps and all 20000 steps failed. When I try to restart this case. the getPartitionNames returns all 20000 steps. In this case, Im facing the problem I mentioned above. The process hangs.

I tried to understand what was going on behind the job by enabling spring debug logs (which took me so long to discover but worth it). I saw a specific set of queries running. they are:

```
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG ResourcelessTransactionManager:755 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG ResourcelessTransactionManager:39 - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@5743a94e]
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG ResourcelessTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastStepExecution]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION from COPY_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? order by JOB_EXECUTION_ID desc]
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:114 - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING from COPY_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from COPY_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:27 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from COPY_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]
2019-02-22 06:40:30 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:30 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT FROM COPY_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2019-02-22 06:40:30 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
2019-02-22 06:40:30 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT FROM COPY_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2019-02-22 06:40:30 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

and so on...

I understood spring is executing **getLastStepExecution** for each failed step one by one. But why is getLastStepExecution done this way? or is there any way we can configure this? like reading all the step executions in bulk and start processing so as to reduce the restart time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting! Can you share the logs where the job is hanging? What is the last log message before it hangs? FTR, we are working on improving the overall performance of the framework for the upcoming v4.2 and partitioning is one of the areas we want to improve (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2716).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Sorry for getting back late. I have updated the question with log details and few more details. Please take a look at it.